# IntelliJ IDEA иконки maven\database стали серыми

Tags: intellij-idea

В общем-то да... иконки стали серыми после перехода на версию IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 x64.
До этого стояла 2017 года. Точную версию не вспомню уже...

Можно их цвета как-то вернуть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нагуглено, не проверено - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10777-legacy-icon-pack-2018-2-

Comment: @StrangerintheQ действительно помогло) За что спасибо! 
Но к сожалению жаль, что плагины возвращают вообще все старые элементы =)
Ну хоть понял... что дело точно не во мне, а просто так решили разработчики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StrangerintheQ ответил на вопрос.

Вся информация тут
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10777-legacy-icon-pack-2018-2-